# UFW SSH deny rule not working

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, nat, ufw

TLDR: I'm trying to block `SSH` connections to a server; the server itself is connected to a `ubuntu` router with `UFW` on it, but external `SSH` connections to the server aren't getting denied, `UFW` doesn't work.

Some context: I've been trying to set up a Linux network with `QEMU/KVM` in `virt-manager`. There is a router with `UFW` on it, which connects via interfaces to a guest network (192.168.150.0/24), an isolated network (192.168.100.0/24), and the Internet (192.168.144.0/24). The `UFW` rules on the router are:

```
~$ sudo ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), allow (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
192.168.100.102 22         DENY IN     Anywhere
192.168.144.0/24 22        ALLOW IN    Anywhere
192.168.150.0/24           ALLOW IN    Anywhere
Anywhere                   ALLOW IN    192.168.150.0/24
192.168.150.0/24           ALLOW IN    192.168.100.0/24
192.168.100.0/24           ALLOW IN    192.168.150.0/24
```

In the isolated network, there is a server with an IP address of 192.168.100.102. I've scanned it with `nmap` from the guest network (which is 192.168.150.0/24) to find any open ports, and found out that `SSH` was opened:

```
~$ nmap -p 0-65535 192.168.100.102
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2023-06-22 13:35
Nmap scan report for 192.168.100.102
Host is up (0.00015s latency).
Not shown: 65535 closed ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 1.37 seconds
```

I restarted `UFW` and `iptables`, it didn't work.

```
sudo ufw reload
sudo service iptables restart
```

I added some `NAT` rules to the beginning of the `/etc/ufw/before.rules` file when I set up the network; maybe they are the issue?

```
# NAT table rules
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [150:14925]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [131:11640]
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.150.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
```